# Fit a longer np array into a shorter but wider panda dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame "p" and a np array "b" as follow

```
p=pd.DataFrame([["j","k","h"],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

j k h
4 5 6
7 8 9


b=np.array([["a",10],["b",20],["c",30],["d",40]])

a 10
b 20
c 30
d 40
```

I want to insert the np array to the dataframe and make become as follow

```
j  k   h
a  10  10 
b  20  20
c  30  30
d  40  40
```

Notice p is wider than b and b is longer than p

Basically:

1. keep the first row of the p
2. insert b into p from second row
3. repeat second column of b to the rest of column of p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use:

```
pd.concat([p.iloc[[0]],
           pd.DataFrame(np.hstack([b, b[:,[1]]]), columns=p.columns)],
          ignore_index=True)
```

output:

```
   0   1   2
0  j   k   h
1  a  10  10
2  b  20  20
3  c  30  30
4  d  40  40
```